# Stamp Editor in ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-viewer, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I want to use Stamp Editor, but I don't want to upload an image from my device. Instead, I want it to pass a specific image when clicked.
How do this?

this my code

```html
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'/assets/pdf-test.pdf'" [height]="'100%'" [customToolbar]="additionalButtons">
</ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
<ng-template #additionalButtons>
    <div id="toolbarViewer">
        <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
            <pdf-toggle-sidebar></pdf-toggle-sidebar>
            <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div>
            <pdf-find-button [showFindButton]="true" [textLayer]="true"></pdf-find-button>
            <pdf-paging-area></pdf-paging-area>
        </div>
        <pdf-zoom-toolbar></pdf-zoom-toolbar>
        <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
            <pdf-rotate-page></pdf-rotate-page>
            <pdf-stamp-editor></pdf-stamp-editor>
            <pdf-presentation-mode></pdf-presentation-mode>
            <pdf-print></pdf-print>
            <pdf-download></pdf-download>
            <div class="verticalToolbarSeparator hiddenSmallView"></div>
            <pdf-toggle-secondary-toolbar></pdf-toggle-secondary-toolbar>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I want it to pass a specific image when clicked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.